# ChartJS – How to show border on empty pie chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have a couple of pie/doughnut charts displayed using **ChartJS**. Usually, they contain data like `[200, 1200, 300]` and `[30, 500]` to give an estimate, but at rare occasions, they will contain `[0, 0, 0]` and `[0, 0]`. The problem then, is that the chart disappears, even though I have a border enabled. I have solved this by adding dummy values to the first element in the arrays, but I don't like how the code looks and want a better way.

Is it possible to make the border visible (a circle) when the array contains only zeroes?

Edit:
I don't seem to get any answers to this question. Is it considered a bug when the border is not showing on empty data or is this intended behavior? I don't know if anyone else has had this problem. I still need to find an elegant way to deal with this issue, and I haven't found one yet.

Comment: A pie chart with data of all 0's could throw a divide by zero when calculating portions if it weren't handled.  A simplified version of how each pieces size in deg is calculated `( 360 / totalOfData ) * data`.  Can't see an elegant solution in the docs. Dummy values may be cleaner than the alternatives I can see, ie. manually drawing over the top(need to handle resize too), or possibly patching/monkey patching a method in  `Chart.controllers.doughnut` to resolve the issue `update` or `updateElement` may be good starting points (a little too tired to look into it further at the min sorry)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My own method of adding a dummy value is probably the best right now, it seems then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not a bug, as the borders are rendered per data item. If all the data is 0s, then every slice has no width, so no border can show (the only other way to handle this scenario for ChartJS would be to give each item equal sizing, which isn't better).

You can add a dummy value without a label and filter the legend and tooltips so that the data is treated like a blank space to the user. In the example below, a check before rendering the chart ensures that if all data points are 0, a data point with a value of 1 is added to the chart with no label. Two datasets are shown to highlight the difference.

```js
let ctx = document.getElementById('chartContainer').getContext('2d');

let data = [[0, 0, 0], [1,2,3]];
let labels = ["A", "B", "C"];
let bgColors = ['yellow', 'orange', 'aquamarine'];

let options = {
  borderWidth: 1,
  borderColor: 'black',
  legend: {
    labels: {
     // Prevent items with undefined labels from appearing in the legend
      filter: (item) => item.text !== undefined
    }
  },
  tooltips: {
    // Prevent items with undefined labels from showing tooltips
   filter: (item, chart) => chart.labels[item.index] !== undefined
  }
}

let chartConfig = {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
      data: data[0],
      backgroundColor: bgColors,
      label: "data",
      borderColor: 'black',
      borderWidth: 2
    }, {
      data: data[1],
      backgroundColor: bgColors,
      label: "data",
      borderColor: 'black',
      borderWidth: 2
    }]
  },
  options: options
}

// Check if data is all 0s; if it is, add dummy data to end with empty label
chartConfig.data.datasets.forEach(dataset => {
  if (dataset.data.every(el => el === 0)) {
    dataset.backgroundColor.push('rgba(255,255,255,0)');
    dataset.data.push(1);
  }
})


let pieChart = new Chart(ctx, chartConfig);
```

```css
.chartContainer {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="chartContainer">
  <canvas id="chartContainer" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
</div>
```